# Multiple language datetime text to standard date format

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime, dayofweek

I'm using `dateutil.parser.parse` in Python to standardize dates. Not all of the dates are in English. Therefore, the standardization process failed with "unknown string format" error. Is there a way to process such dates or at least avoid the error?

Sample date formats:

- Wed, 17 Oct 2001 11:49:53 -0700 (PDT)
- Wednesday, February 06, 2002 8:55 AM
- Domingo 25 de Noviembre de 2001 08:02

Comment: *"or at least avoid the error"* - `try` and `except WhateverError`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use a different date parsing package?  Maybe give [dateparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser) a try?

Install using pip:

```
pip install dateparser
```

Example usage:

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> timestamp1 = "Wed, 17 Oct 2001 11:49:53 -0700 (PDT)"
>>> timestamp2 = "Wednesday, February 06, 2002 8:55 AM"
>>> timestamp3 = "Domingo 25 de Noviembre de 2001 08:02"
>>> dateparser.parse(timestamp1)
datetime.datetime(2001, 10, 17, 20, 49, 53)
>>> dateparser.parse(timestamp2)
datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 6, 8, 55)
>>> dateparser.parse(timestamp3)
datetime.datetime(2001, 11, 25, 8, 2)
```

dateparser documentation:  https://dateparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/